# CountIFS function with multiple criteria and values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to make some statistics in Excel, where I easilly can farm data from our company.

I have been using COUNTIFS formula quite a lot since it is great regarding the data I have. However now I have stumbled upon a problem I can not figure out.

```
=COUNTIFS('Worksheet1'!Q:Q,"NAME",'Worksheet1'!J:J,"Level 3",'Worksheet1'!E:E,"<=17")
```

The cell above shows exactly what I would like, there is nothing wrong with this line. It is just shown as an example of what I would like. This works because I have a worksheet with over 1500 rows in and there is other data relevant for me. This formula is looking for the amount of people on "Level 3" from the age 17 and under, I also get the correct number.

```
=COUNTIFS('Worksheet1'!Q:Q,"NAME",'Worksheet1'!J:J,"Level 3",'Worksheet1'!E:E,"<=36"&">=50")
```

This is where it gets problematic, because I have the same exact criteria as the other cell, the difference is that I am looking for the number of people aged between 36 and 50 fitting into the same criteria. I always get the wrong values even when I try different techniques. I have tried combining two formulas, but this didn`t work either.

```
=COUNTIFS('Worksheet1'!E:E,"<=26",'Worksheet1'!E:E,">=35")&COUNTIFS('Worksheet1'!Q:Q,"NAME",'Worksheet1'!J:J,"Level 3")
```

So I guess my question is: Is there some way for the COUNTIFS formula to check in between two values in a criteria range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close.  You just need to check the two criteria **separately**

```
>=36
<=50
```

So the formula might look like:

```
COUNTIFS('Worksheet1'!Q:Q,"NAME",'Worksheet1'!J:J,"Level 3",'Worksheet1'!E:E,">=36",Worksheet1!E:E,"<=50")
```